# is this code valid for password hashing?

Tags: php, md5, salt, sha512

is this a valid code for salt generation.what does it do if it is invalid then please explain what i should do and please a little less technical im only 15

```
$password='123'//test password
$salt=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(rand());//generate salt
$prehash_password=hash('sha512',$password);//pre hash the password 
$final_password=hash('sha512',$password.$salt)//generate the final password
```

result....(too long so cropped it)

```
=m]ˆÂýÇâ&-Ù©Þ}§˜ü=l|‹|oÓÌ×±[ý’p'lJÛ|›¦nXÝxÜ†9óÔ¢¤ÿ‰"µ^¾õJ JI^íó,•±†û½L›T0*Stÿ#s´Ë§ÔMgå.£J§èeRzù/‡üœ¿ª¡ Ç¹áuT¯ '0¯ÄŒÐ²A@ü •uuYRpýš™ü5%P—í¬ïr‚×ODÜ—´“„?”öÛž;Bí#Þcõ&¾qLEâ« |Z¯ÔÐö%R•9âÇ¸—•êäxZ³ÎÉ¶ÉêS\™!qóœ[)ÚúÞçøƒŠº¾*Ü/X"Œê@µð¶¨$p1£B5iÚ Ú†õÊ¬É¦E3^ür¾auD»ëêA)d„ÏHzYÁepƒê¬~ô¡œ8e‡ñˆÖM&èæ<ëâM"-¹uSÂÖøsBŒiÓÑ!³ÊÅwÛÃ¶>kHåO'dyÁ(<Ýx´Ÿì¸¤˜)èÀ©@ëQæ‚Ëã:04q-‡è—žÄ­"tÌÀ±IŒW1p–Ì‡bïV¢¼-$»¥ˆlË*Ê^¡´ZK ×±›mßhœôNþ`‰û§4p9 þ]Ùö®u*)ú24qØI£–]†#8kÐ>a…t fö¾¶+k—a ?L¯¶ƒÎµÜz‘k†—)+¥qþÞ \®qÔª|ãO¹¥ô?I°®íÉ¨‘‡3 dÿë€ìV&"+Ï}*Lí€Ÿh"p  Ø"ð¶Øäç6ˆkƒ¹òÓ@FK²Ä?åüï<:CˆšÛƒ1J®b™ý)žy´ÔÄ¶a™_Áïx^—õö6Ãqc€õš¾©÷M—¡å´7ÁÑ©Nà›¶AÚ¢öEM:"¶Ž4iáîµ&Cþ²Pû¶££.ÿ *?©ñÞ`&ÞGøó§¦_B¸‡h–¦éÞæ'è£©n¥êý5‘¿kcñV‰1?xçÛ#”C0ÒÁià¿0Ÿ¥çWdÅ˜]íhæS'ã'–ÿðò§ü‡ì¨šãfïï Á0ó7kÀ%±N“£\Br)"úklìŠ¢˜˜[’€:º–Í  GaùÛaçˆwsÔÚ‚õòSd›±ltWZ›è_¹ªÿã§%ÉÞxî³«ŸKÊMUYÜJ@Šý+BBL¤®Š±    Â„¼‚ÈûæÀŠBñã“„º/oú–·fJäƒrÀ°‡¤N2¸×kìô"aõÙ%ÚÂWŸÿ–†Œ»Còc?…£Rw4ËZ_W§{b™”î—/Ä¾›:ºj;U.½ÓM “É¥8T37?¿UÃh5Ä½>éÎÔášÄxÃ€¥ä·$í÷äÕÖ·¿Oowç<ÖÅ!XNâjW”öb1GâÔ¯yYÇ+¶pL´[sŠÍT.×KXNK“kh-ñ@bÌÜ^Ü÷]é ¿}fkøD‡0GE îŽï˜;pÂsŠ¶ZfÀ§1gjõÂcøwãj•‡'BšÓ{»£¬²BhaA2ÿT Ë~S{‹øÏàïnñhÁn ýˆÜzŽ*`5ÉŽAsqaùðÄ¶ü¿ƒ 5g>ë¥Uå!-£SÂr–ELÿ*à&;½¤&›y™Ž6¼³ªø OÌ‡MP÷G©‹:ø_•ÜAaA«jb;‹¨ÓÅ Ä¹‰¤¼l*S ï?ö„óÑ    žsÌ=,&å x— a´è2éòyÄlÝŠ*žÄ¥ÆnÀ¨ã³¡ ÝòÆFƒDÁ*DÂ   ;™±™½fÀßÃ¥‹{â«ZËÅøÁY‚Œ”².—ÆÀMuüÃÙR™;c6ì€Î®û°Éƒ„bÐ–{íWáßõíì’¬¾ßaÙ°^læ¿r{ƒ,ãaÃ¬?ZÞ‚á>m9‚€’Ñ§Ñú\VFÏ\b¶c'E¨)óå€Â˜¾bæ¿;nðî¶Äê=fè8cÊ©"¹K sF¢Æš³   ²ˆô6*®&Øç$î6ÐZÆú”Ž‹S¹)šå‡j¶ý¥¹3áBy+ìç°ÏHHg®™:ä`Oà^4Æ–(Øx$…ÖýdÎÞfvr"ÙCU¼Áë¸;½›ÂMy.fRlÓûñ9HÕ6V•.–‚“3¬ig_HSÀíñæ…ïþ­qž—7¾_;ó«(«ãøguBš"ã·pÓïvŠªÜ²•tÚÒ=Jî„d|¤MxžŠÝ’Œ>`
```

Comment: are you storing the salt?

Comment: what does storing the salt mean?

Comment: @Yasin: It means... literally that.  Are you saving (storing) the created salt anywhere?

Comment: You will need the salt when you come to verify the password...

Comment: yes in a seperate column

Comment: When you say your DB is vulnerable, are you sure the problem is with your password hashing?

Comment: I usually suggest against homebrewed password hashing schemes.  Try using a pre-made one, like the one built into PHP 5.5 (http://php.net/password).  There's a version for older PHP versions too (https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @knittl yes by vunerability i mean i am currently using md5 hence it is vunerable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using that, I would recommend using BCrypt or if you are using PHP 5.5 or up, use **password_hash**.

[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Even if you're using PHP 5.3.7 or above, you can still use password_hash with the author's [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)